# NSMutableArray EXC_BAD_EXCESS SIGBUS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, cgimage

I've the following code which causes crashes after sometime as i've set the below code in a timer:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = UIGetScreenImage();
[array addObject:(id)cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

Where initiallly i've declared `array` as:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The timer goes well till 10 seconds as timer is of 1/10 seconds after 10 seconds it crashes.

I think the application crashes because of `EXC_BAD_EXCESS` but dont know how to solve.
Can anybody help in solving the problem?

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Do you get any warning at this line...? 
clean and rebuild the project to see if there is any warning on this line or not....

Comment: No there is no warning at this line as i'm running in device, the crash logs shows the EXC_BAD_EXCESS

Answer (score 0):

addObject: will raise an exception if the object is nil. Try this:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; //designated initializer
CGImageRef cgImage = UIGetScreenImage();
if(cgImage)
{
    [array addObject:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
}
```

Comment: I'm continously adding to array so how can i initialize with capacity of 1. Is there any other way to implement this logic?

Comment: The capacity of 1 is just an initial memory reserve, NSMutableArray will expand as needed. If you know that very soon after the allocation, you will be adding at least twelve objects, then use initWithCapacity:12. The idea is to give NSMutableArray a reasonable estimation of the amount of memory it should reserve, it's not the maximum capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're supposed to be releasing cgImage?

I don't see documentation for UIGetScreenImage(), but if it follows the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), I would not expect you to need to release the object (because the function does not have "Create" or "Copy" in its name).

EDIT:
I've since found several [references](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIImage#UIGetScreenImage) that say that you *do* need to release the image, despite the name of the function. (Which has apparently been renamed `UICreateScreenImage()` in the 3.2 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Developer Forum to UIGetScreenImage():

> As you use this function, please note
>   that it returns a retained CGImageRef
>   and manage your memory accordingly.